# Why we need inversion when a clause starts with a negative adverb?

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-inversion

Why is inversion needed when a clause starts with a negtive adverb? When a clause starts with neither, nor, never, we need inversion.

**Examples**

1. Never will you go to school.
2. Nor will I do that.
3. Neither do I etc.

If I put anything in front of the subject, the verb goes to second position. Why is that?

Comment: But: *Neither **you went** nor **I went** to the fair*. So, inversion is not always required. It's the addition of an auxiliary verb that's key here—and in a way that's similar to it being *Will I go to school?* rather than *I will go to school?* (The latter is is only used when repeating a previous statement, never when asking a question without a prior reference.)

Comment: The Irish have their intractable question; the English have their language.