# Nor + inversion or no inversion?

Tags: conjunctions, subject-verb-inversion

My teacher showed me these examples at the lesson about conjunctions:

> a) She does not eat meat, nor does she drink milk.
>
> b) My grandfather could neither read nor write, but he was a very wise person.

I am wondering, why in sentence (a) inversion is used, but in the other sentence it's not. Why couldn't it be:

> She does not eat meat, nor drink milk.

or, analogically:

> My grandfather could neither read, nor could he write...

Is this because in the sentence (b) the conjunction "neither...nor" is used but in the other sentence it's just "nor"?

Comment: No reason other than the writer's choice.  _She neither eats meat nor drinks milk_ would be a valid version as well.

Comment: "She does not eat meat, nor ___ drink milk".  The gap is understood as "does she", so there is in fact inversion.

Comment: This question is about nor and inversion: ['Nor WE are' and 'Nor ARE we'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/596871/nor-we-are-and-nor-are-we); [this covers it a bit too](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/535802/why-we-need-inversion-when-a-clause-starts-with-a-negative-adverb).

Comment: _Nor_ is a negative. When a negative is fronted, inversion occurs: _Never/*Occasionally/*In the last decade have I seen such things,_ but _Occasionally/In the last decade I have seen such things._ See ["_any_ Questions?"](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/anyquestions.pdf)

Comment: @BillJ Why isn't it a coordination with the coordinates *eat meat* and *nor drink milk*?